# How to define a method to enter a new item to an existing hashtable in java?

Tags: java, methods, hash, hashtable

When I want to add an item to a predefined hashtable, it is usually simple. But whenever I want to define a method like `addNewCustomer()` and try to use `customerHashtable.put(...);` function inside of that method, it doesn't work. Please help me define a method that works with an existing hashtable and let me add new objects (customers in this case) to it.

Here is the code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

           Hashtable<Integer, Customer> customerHashtable = new Hashtable<Integer, Customer>();
           customerHashtable.put (1, new Customer("david", "+13035003433", new Address("AR", "77555")));

           Customer customer = new Customer("mark", "13035003433", new Address("AR", "77200"));

           public void addNewCustomers(int key, Customer customer) { 
           customerHashtable.put(key, customer);
           System.out.println(customerHashtable.get(key).toString());
           }
    }

}
```

Comment: You would have to pass the `customerHashtable` to the function, or make it a class field.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn’t work? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I am new to programming. Can you please explain it little more? I also copied the code I want to accomplished above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your `addNewCutomers()` method outside your `main` method and create a class field for your `HashTable`. Assuming you are okay with a static context, it could look like this:

```
public class HashtableDemo {

    static Hashtable<Integer, Customer> customerHashtable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        customerHashtable = new Hashtable<Integer, Customer>();
        customerHashtable.put (1, new Customer("david", "+13035003433", new Address("AR", "77555")));

        Customer customer = new Customer("mark", "13035003433", new Address("AR", "77200"));
        addNewCustomers(2, customer);
    }

    public static void addNewCustomers(int key, Customer customer) { 
        customerHashtable.put(key, customer);
        System.out.println(customerHashtable.get(key).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing it. It worked. I have one question though. Since we have used a static method, does it mean that we can also call that method from other classes? @TobiasGeiselmann

Comment: Correct. Since it is a `public` method, you can call it from any other class too.